# Deserializing dictionary return Null

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I'm working with a Web API and trying to receive a dictionary as parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public IDictionary<string, string> Get(IDictionary<string,string> myDictionaryAsParameter)
```

To call it, I'm creating a url querystring with:

```
string endpoint = "http//localhost:1122/api/MyController/?myDictionaryAsParameter=" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters)
```

When debugging the code, the web API method dictionary parameter is Null.

If I change the web API signature to :

```
[HttpGet]
public IDictionary<string, string> Get(string myDictionaryAsParameter)
{
    var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myDictionaryAsParameter);
}
```

It gets parsed correctly.

How should I encode/serialize my dictionary object to send it in url querystring and get it correctly parsed by web API method signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public IDictionary<string, string> Get(IDictionary<string,string> myParameter)
{
}
```

Then you'll have to pass `myDictionaryAsParameter` via the body and change to `[HttpPost]`, since Web API doesn't support a body parameter in `HttpGet`.

A few tests I've tried show that only simple parameters are read via URL e.g.

```
// For URL/value
// I've tried this with complex objects - doesn't work with complex objects

[HttpGet]
[Route("{myParameter}")]
public IDictionary<string, string> Get(string myParameter)
{
}
```

or:

```
// For URL?myParameter=value
// Haven't tried this with complex objects - might not work with complex objects

[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public IDictionary<string, string> Get(string myParameter = "default")
{
}
```

However, you could try this with the last option (by adding a default value).

Also, the vNext of Web API gives additional routing options, you could try this with VS2015 and the new Web API version.